# XSL - How to disable output escaping for an attribute?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-designer

I've had the following `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="http://myserver/_forms?url={@FileRef}&amp;id=5">...</a>
```

One of the files is called `"File's got apostrophe.xml"`. The output of the XSL is:

```
<a href="http://myserver/_forms?url=/blah/File&amp;#39;s got apostrophe.xml&id=5">...</a>
```

The problem is that the apostrophe is HTML-escaped (twice?) into `&amp;#39;`, which breaks the link.

I've also tried using `<xsl:attribute>`, with same results:

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('http://myserver/_forms?url=', @FileRef, '&amp;id=5')"
         disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

Outputting `<xsl:value-of select="@FileRef" disable-output-escaping="yes" />` works well - the unescaped value is printed on the page.

How can I set the attribute without escaping the string?

Comment: have you tried storing the string to a variable and outputting that ?

Comment: have you tried different xslt-processors/browsers?

Comment: @Gaby - I didn't try that, I thought of it, but it didn't make sense. It didn't seem better than outputting the `@FileRef` field. Are you referring the the whole `<a>` tag, similar to tpeczek's answer?

Comment: @fx42 - No I haven't. It might work differently on another processor, but since I'm using SharePoint, I don't really get to choose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can generate your <a> as text:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;a href="</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('http://myserver/_forms?url=', @FileRef, '&amp;id=5')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">" &gt;/a&lt;</xsl:text>
```

Comment: That's a pretty good idea, looks like this is going to work. I'll check on Sunday when I'm back to work. Thanks!

Comment: That worked, though the result is exceptionally ugly. What a shame for that next developer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm a bit late on this, but I think the attribute tag is the way to, you just don't want to concat...

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    http://myserver/_forms?url=<xsl:value-of select="@FileRef" disable-output-escaping="yes" />&amp;id=5
  </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

Comment: I had this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887016/disable-output-escaping-not-working-for-attribute-in-xlst

Comment: (source xslt specs:)It is an error for output escaping to be disabled for a text node that is used for something other than a text node in the result tree. Thus, it is an error to disable output escaping for an xsl:value-of or xsl:text element that is used to generate the string-value of a comment, processing instruction or attribute node;