# Disable output escaping not working for attribute in xslt

Tags: xslt, attributes

I have the following xml-node :

```
<name>P &amp; P</name>
```

And following XSL

```
<a href="example.htm" >

    <xsl:attribute name="title">
       <xsl:value-of select="name" disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:attribute>    


     <xsl:value-of select="name" disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:value-of>
</a>
```

That compiles to this HTML

```
<a href="example.com" title="P &amp;amp; P">
  P &amp; P
</a>
```

So the non-escaping worked for the value (the text between `<A></A>`) but not for the attribute.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From an OP's comment**:

> I need this xml (P & P) in the title attribute of an HTML tag. A
>   better solution is most welcome!

**What you need to generate can be done perfectly without D-O-E**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <a href="example.htm" title="{.}">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>P &amp; P</t>
```

the wanted, correct result is produced:

```
<a href="example.htm" title="P &amp; P">P &amp; P</a>
```

Comment: +1 : cause you are right. However, I simplified the example, and in my case sth. different is happening. I have to figure out what now. Tx.

Comment: @Peter: You have to provide a more precise example then. Your current question is completely answered.

Comment: @Dimtitre, in fact the question intende was "why isn't output escaping working in xslt?" I guess the correct answer is :"cause it's designed that way" .  Nevertheless, If I find time I will provide a precise example, otherwise, I'll happily accept your answer a bit later. Tx. for your trouble in any case.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, D-O-E is only defined within text nodes -- not attributes. My answer adresses your comment in which you stated what you actually wanted to achieve, and provides a D-O-E - less solution :)

Comment: Since the answer 'no it's  not possible' is kind of lame, I accept your answer as indeed an answer on my commant.  I still hope if I find time to post a better sample you'll help me out too.

Comment: @Peter: Please, let me know via a comment when you have posted the new question -- I am glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking around and I guess this is why : (if I understand correctly) ?

Out of the specs : (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)

> It is an error for output escaping to be disabled for a text node that
>   is used for something other than a text node in the result tree. ***Thus,
>   it is an error to disable output escaping for an xsl:value-of or
>   xsl:text element that is used to generate the string-value of a
>   comment, processing instruction or attribute node;*** it is also an error
>   to convert a result tree fragment to a number or a string if the
>   result tree fragment contains a text node for which escaping was
>   disabled. In both cases, an XSLT processor may signal the error; if it
>   does not signal the error, it must recover by ignoring the
>   disable-output-escaping attribute.

So disabling output for escaping an attribute is just not possible apparantly.  The workaround that I see is to build a string 'by hand' as [XSL - How to disable output escaping for an attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921123/xsl-how-to-disable-output-escaping-for-an-attribute)

Still hard to believe that I'm not missing sth. trivial here.

Comment: Correct, d-o-e doesn't work for attributes. Question is, why are you using d-o-e in the first place? There are a few valid use cases, but most of the time, it's an ugly hack and better solutions are possible.

Comment: I need this xml  (P &amp; P) in the title attribute of an HTML tag. A better solution is most welcome!

Comment: No "to build a string 'by hand' " approach is necessary -- see my answer. :)